# Setting non-contiguous text selection on iTerm and Chrome in OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, iterm2

How do I set a selection of non-contiguous text in the latest version of iTerm2 and Chrome in OS X 10.8.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of applications – iTerm2 and Google Chrome included – don't support this function. You cannot select non-contiguous text here.

In fact, this only works in apps like TextEdit or Pages, but not even in other OS X native apps such as Safari. Non-contiguous selection isn't even a feature of the most basic [`NSTextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html), because you can only set one range for selection here. For non-continuous selection you'd use [`NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but then again applications don't use this to render text (like a browser or terminal does) – you'd use it to edit text.

In short: Not possible unless the developers implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox supports [non-contiguous text selection](http://www.watchingthenet.com/firefox-3-tip-how-to-select-multiple-areas-of-text.html).  Simply hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> while selecting multiple text regions with the mouse.